# sed - double into single braces if line starts with pattern

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a .bib file exported from Mendeley where the title entries are wrapped in double braces, as in:

```
title = {{Nonparametric Permutation Tests for {\{PET{\}} functional Neuroimaging Experiments: A Primer with examples}},
```

I would like to use sed to check if a line starts with "title", and if yes, to remove the first double braces, and the final ones before the comma, resulting in:

```
title = {Nonparametric Permutation Tests for {\{PET{\}} functional Neuroimaging Experiments: A Primer with examples},
```

I know there is good documentation around on how to check for a starting pattern, how to escape metacharacters, and how to save matches for later use on the substitution, but I'm inexperienced with regex and my attempts so far lead to garbage or errors (e.g.):

```
sed: 1: "/^title/s/\{\{[^]]*\}\} ...": RE error: invalid repetition count(s)
```

Does anyone know a solution for this substitution problem?

Comment: try `sed "s/^\(title = \){{\([^{]\+\)}},$/\1{\2},/g" input.txt`

Comment: This one didn't work..

Comment: @dpgomez: Are you using GNU Sed?  Did you add anything like `-r` to the `sed` command line?  GNU `sed` really complicates things because (AFAIUI) it tries to divine whether it should use extended regular expressions if the `-r` is missing, and in a case with braces forming a part of the match string like this, it is practically certain to guess wrong.

Comment: I'm using sed on OS X

Comment: And you're not adding a `-E` option to the Mac OS X Sed command, are you?

Comment: no, I was calling it with "sed -i .bak 's/{//;s/}//' library.bib". Calling the above expression with -E works but some entries are still in there.

Comment: When I run: `echo "title = {{The UNIX-HATERS Handbook}}," | sed '/^title = /s/{{\(.*\)}},/{\1},/'` the output is `title = {The UNIX-HATERS Handbook},` — which is what you want, is it not?

Comment: Yes, it works for 99% of the lines, but misses the one I just edited on the question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do the trick.

```
$ echo "title = {{Nonparametric Permutation Tests for {\{PET{\}} functional Neuroimaging Experiments: A Primer with examples}}," |
> sed 's/^title = {{\(.*\)}},$/title = {\1},/'
title = {Nonparametric Permutation Tests for {\{PET{\}} functional Neuroimaging Experiments: A Primer with examples},
$ echo "title = {{The UNIX-HATERS Handbook}}," |
> sed 's/^title = {{\(.*\)}},$/title = {\1},/'
title = {The UNIX-HATERS Handbook},
$
```

Compared with what I proposed in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33977137/sed-double-into-single-braces-if-line-starts-with-pattern/33977407#comment55711018_33977137) earlier, the regex has a `$` to anchor the `}},` to the end of the line and rigorously requires the `title = {{` at the start of the line, though as the ghastligram title doesn't have a comma after the embedded `}}`, the original `sed` script also works.  As long as the titles are always on one line, regardless of how long it is, this should do the trick.  I made the match more rigorous than in the comment so it won't mangle any title that has already been converted from double braces to single braces; the previous editions of the script would have mangled some variations on the really complex title (ones which contained `{{` and `}}` in the body of the title), but this won't unless the original actually contained `title = {{{Brace yourselves}}}`.

Tested with Mac OS X 10.11.1 and using both BSD (Mac OS X) `sed` and GNU `sed`; same output.